# Add two numbers without knowing exact type in Java

Tags: java, numbers

I have two Numbers they maybe integer float or double, how to add them in java,  Number object cannot add each other.

I can only test there type(class) and convert one by one, it's ugly (lots of if else) and obscure， any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke Number.doubleValue() and add:

```
Number n1 = new Double(10.3d);
Number n2 = new Integer(12);
System.out.println(n1.doubleValue() + n2.doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

If precision loss is acceptable, you can add their double (or even BigDecimal) values:

```
double result = a.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue();
```

Otherwise, you will have implement all cases (which you can do only do for common types, as Number is an abstract class).

To be honest, this is very likely to be a sign of bad conception.